# Running codes of articles on github in spyder

Tags: python, github, anaconda, spyder

I want to use **node2vec** method for interaction prediction. I download the python codes from github. In readme file it says:

*To run node2vec on Zachary's karate club network, execute the following command from the project home directory:*

```
python src/main.py --input graph/karate.edgelist --output emb/karate.emd
```

**I confuse how can I use these codes in "spyder" with my interaction file?**

I use python 3 in windows 10.
Thanks for your answers in advance.